# Find and insert tags using regex

Tags: python, regex, calibre

I am converting a book from PDF to epub in calibre. But the titles are not inside header tags, hence trying a python function using regex to replace it.

example text:

```
<p class="calibre1"><a id="p1"></a>Chapter 370: Slamming straight on</p>
<p class="softbreak"> </p>
<p class="calibre1">Hearing Yan Zhaoge’s suggestion, the Jade Sea City martial practitioners here were all stunned.</p>
<p class="calibre1"><a id="p7"></a>Chapter 372: Yan Zhaoge’s plan</p>
<p class="softbreak"> </p>
<p class="calibre1">Yan Zhaoge and Ah Hu sat on Pan-Pan’s back, black water swirling about Pan-Pan’s entire body, keeping away the seawater as he shot forward at lightning speed.</p>
```

i tried using regex with

```
def replace(match, number, file_name, metadata, dictionaries, data, functions, *args, **kwargs):
    
    pattern = r"</a>(?i)chapter [0-9]+: [\w\s]+(.*)<br>"
    list = re.findall(pattern, match.group())
    
    for x in list:
        x = "</a>(?i)chapter [0-9]+: [\w\s]+(.?)<br>"
        x = s.split("</a>", 1)[0] + '</a><h2>' + s.split("a>",1)[1]
        x = s.split("<br>", 1)[0] + '</h2><br>' + s.split("<br>",1)[1]
    return match.group()
```

and

```
def replace(match, number, file_name, metadata, dictionaries, data, functions, *args, **kwargs):
    pattern = r"</a>(?i)chapter [0-9]+: [\w\s]+(.*)<br>"
    s.replace(re.match(pattern, s), r'<h2>$0')
```

But still not getting expected result. what i want is...

## Input

`</a>Chapter 370: Slamming straight on</p>`

## Output

`</a><h2>Chapter 370: Slamming straight on</h2></p>`

h2 tag is to be added in all similar instances

Comment: you probably should use a xml parser instead. don't parse xml with regex

Comment: https://www.volarenovels.com/novel/historys-strongest-senior-brother? T&C do not allow to modify their content

Comment: I'm not modifying any content, I'm converting to epub to read in mobile, and as a programmer, i'm curious to learn how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`regex` shoudn't be used to parse xml. See : 
[Why it's not possible to use regex to parse HTML/XML: a formal explanation in layman's terms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6751339/7652544)
(`Why shouldn't you..`would be a better title)

However, you might use BeautifulSoup instead:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data = """<p class="calibre1"><a id="p1"></a>Chapter 370: Slamming straight on</p>
<p class="softbreak"> </p>
<p class="calibre1">Hearing Yan Zhaoge’s suggestion, the Jade Sea City martial practitioners here were all stunned.</p>
<p class="calibre1"><a id="p7"></a>Chapter 372: Yan Zhaoge’s plan</p>
<p class="softbreak"> </p>
<p class="calibre1">Yan Zhaoge and Ah Hu sat on Pan-Pan’s back, black water swirling about Pan-Pan’s entire body, keeping away the seawater as he shot forward at lightning speed.</p>
i t"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')


for x in soup.find_all('p', {'class':'calibre1'}):

    link = x.find('a')
    title = x.text
    corrected_title = soup.new_tag('h2')
    corrected_title.append(title)

    if link:
        x.string=''
        corrected_title = soup.new_tag('h2')
        corrected_title.append(title)
        link.append(corrected_title)
        x.append(link)

print(soup.body)
```

**Output**

```
<body>
    <p class="calibre1">
        <a id="p1">
            <h2>Chapter 370: Slamming straight on</h2>
        </a>
    </p>
    <p class="softbreak"> </p>
    <p class="calibre1">Hearing Yan Zhaoge’s suggestion, the Jade Sea City martial practitioners here were all stunned.</p>
    <p class="calibre1">
        <a id="p7">
            <h2>Chapter 372: Yan Zhaoge’s plan</h2>
        </a>
    </p>
    <p class="softbreak"> </p>
    <p class="calibre1">Yan Zhaoge and Ah Hu sat on Pan-Pan’s back, black water swirling about Pan-Pan’s entire body, keeping away the seawater as he shot forward at lightning speed.</p>
    i t
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks @Sebastien but allows only regex unfortunately. And this doesnt work either.

Comment: @Andruraj, my shame, I corrected it. Just to be curious, why would only `regex` work?

Comment: I'm using calibre for converting pdf to epub and this only allows regex. Hope that clarifies enough.

Answer (score 0):

[Jean-François](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6451573/jean-fran%c3%a7ois-fabre)'s comment would be much better to follow, yet if we might have to, my guess is that we'd start with this expression:

```
(<\/a>)([^<]+)?(<\/p>)
(<\/a>)(chapter\s+[0-9]+[^<]+)?(<\/p>)
```

being replaced with:

```
\1<h2>\2</h2>\3
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/UpTPr9/1)

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/HEQOHQ/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(<\/a>)(chapter\s+[0-9]+[^<]+)?(<\/p>)"

test_str = ("<p class=\"calibre1\"><a id=\"p1\"></a>Chapter 370: Slamming straight on</p>\n"
    "<p class=\"softbreak\"> </p>\n"
    "<p class=\"calibre1\">Hearing Yan Zhaoge’s suggestion, the Jade Sea City martial practitioners here were all stunned.</p>\n"
    "<p class=\"calibre1\"><a id=\"p7\"></a>Chapter 372: Yan Zhaoge’s plan</p>\n"
    "<p class=\"softbreak\"> </p>\n"
    "<p class=\"calibre1\">Yan Zhaoge and Ah Hu sat on Pan-Pan’s back, black water swirling about Pan-Pan’s entire body, keeping away the seawater as he shot forward at lightning speed.</p>")

subst = "\\1<h2>\\2</h2>\\3"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Comment: Thanks @Emma. But it also detects </a></p> tags (for both regex)